# Is there a pythonic way to insert space characters at random positions of an existing string?

Tags: string, python

is there a pythonic way to implement this:

> Insert `/spaces_1/` `U+0020 SPACE`
>   characters into `/key_1/` at random
>   positions other than the start or end
>   of the string.

?

There `/spaces_1/` is integer and `/key_1/` is arbitrary existing string.

Thanks.

Comment: How is the number of spaces inserted distributed, given the size of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list based solution:

```
import random

def insert_spaces(s):
    s = list(s)
    for i in xrange(len(s)-1):
        while random.randrange(2):
            s[i] = s[i] + ' '
    return ''.join(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

strings in python are immutable, so you can't change them in place. However:

```
import random

def insert_space(s):
    r = random.randint(1, len(s)-1)
    return s[:r] + ' ' + s[r:]

def insert_spaces(s):
    for i in xrange(random.randrange(len(s))):
        s = insert_space(s)
    return s
```

Comment: I think converting to a list first is more efficient so, isn't it?

Comment: @eigenein, it depends. I'd suggest trying both and seeing which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to arbitrarily decide you never want two spaces inserted adjacently - each insertion point used only once - and that "insert" excludes "append" and "prepend".

First, construct a list of insertion points...

```
insert_points = range (1, len (mystring))
```

Pick out a random selection from that list, and sort it...

```
import random
selected = random.sample (insert_points, 5)
selected.sort ()
```

Make a list of slices of your string...

```
selected.append (len (mystring))  #  include the last slice
temp = 0  #  start with first slice
result = []
for i in selected :
  result.append (mystring [temp:i])
  temp = i
```

Now, built the new string...

```
" ".join (result)
```

Comment: That's interesting but slightly long way. =)

Comment: @eigenein - there was already at least one sane answer, so I aimed for the slightly insane niche. FWIW, there may be a way to avoid the for-loop bit - a built-in that splits a string at specified positions. I didn't think to check for that at the time.

Comment: why not, selected = random.sample(insert_points, random.randrange(len(mystring))) ?

Comment: @dan - because I didn't think of it - neat idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just because no one used `map` yet:

```
import random
''.join(map(lambda x:x+' '*random.randint(0,1), s)).strip()
```

Comment: A beautiful solution. It's a pity that it doesn't insert exactly defined number of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This method inserts a given number of spaces to a random position in a string and takes care that there are no double spaces after each other:

```
import random

def add_spaces(s, num_spaces):
    assert(num_spaces <= len(s) - 1)

    space_idx = []
    space_idx.append(random.randint(0, len(s) - 2))
    num_spaces -= 1

    while (num_spaces > 0):
        idx = random.randint(0, len(s) - 2)
        if (not idx in space_idx):
            space_idx.append(idx)
            num_spaces -= 1

    result_with_spaces = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        result_with_spaces += s[i]
        if i in space_idx:
            result_with_spaces += ' '

    return result_with_spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more than one space, then go

```
s[:r] + ' '*n + s[r:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it comes...

```
def thePythonWay(s,n):
    n = max(0,min(n,25))
    where = random.sample(xrange(1,len(s)),n)
    return ''.join("%2s" if i in where else "%s" for i in xrange(len(s))) % tuple(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

We will randomly choose the locations where spaces will be added - after char 0, 1, ... n-2 of the string (n-1 is the last character, and we will not place a space after that); and then insert the spaces by replacing the characters in the specified locations with (the original character) + ' '. This is along the lines of Steve314's solution (i.e. keeping the assumption that you don't want consecutive spaces - which limits the total spaces you can have), but without using lists.

Thus:

```
import random
def insert_random_spaces(original, amount):
    assert amount > 0 and amount < len(original)
    insert_positions = sorted(random.sample(xrange(len(original) - 1), amount))
    return ''.join(
        x + (' ' if i in insert_positions else '')
        for (i, x) in enumerate(original)
    )
```